# I can't connect to my database using java

Tags: java, database

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt=null;
ResultSet rset=null;
String jdbc_url="jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@bassam-desktop:1521:XE";
String query="";
try
{
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc_url);
    stmt=(Statement) conn.createStatement();
    query="select first_name" +"from employees"+"where employeed_id=100";
    rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println(rset.getString(1));


}
catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("result error");
        }
finally{
    try{
        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in closing");
    }
}
```

I'm getting both errors in the results window, what is the problem? hr password is correct, my host name is correct, isn't it the one you get from "Computer Name" after you right click on "My Computer" in windows xp ?

Edit: After using e.getMessage(), i got this..

`result error, ResultSet.next was not called`

Comment: have you tried with localhost instead hostname?

Comment: @localhost:1521:XE ?
it didn't work

Comment: Always look at the exception before asking SO. Use printStackTrace() int the catch clauses.

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot, but it's almost definitely a problem in the `jdbc-url`. Have you successfully connected to the database using your IDE? I use [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org) and it has a great tool for connecting to databases. If you can't connect using that tool, you can't connect in code either.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you're including the [`ojdbc6.jar`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) in your classpath. That's very important.

Comment: I am using netbeans aswell, how do I use this tool ?

Comment: Exceptions contain meaningful error messages, but you don't care about them. Read them.

Comment: remember a space between employees and where.

Comment: When you close the statement your resultset will close also. You're going to have a problem when you try and exceute that query. As previously mentioned, your url to the database is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message of the exception, that you have put in the comments, tells you what's wrong:

> result error, ResultSet.next was not called

You forgot to call ResultSet.next() before accessing the first row of the result set:

```
if (rset.next()) {
    System.out.println(rset.getString(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using Netbeans IDE, you can try connecting with their [built in tool](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html). That should help you get the `jdbc_url` right (which is almost certainly the problem). Also, don't forget to download and include in your classpath the [`ojdbc6.jar`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) (which would definitely be the problem if you're not including it).

Comment: After using e.getMessage(), i got this..

result error, ResultSet.next was not called

Comment: Which line is the error thrown on... That makes it sound like you connect successfully...

Answer (score 0):

The e variable represent the exception. try to print the e.getMessage() or print the stack trace with e.printStackTrace() to understand better the problem.

Comment: After using e.getMessage(), i got this..

result error, ResultSet.next was not called

Answer (score 0):

```
 ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
 while(rset.next()){
     //Code that works with results
 }
```